# Convert Bean to XML

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I'm trying to parse an VO to write it in xsl sheet. I had to use wutka.jox library (it's one of the project's features).

I'm doing this:

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
JOXBeanWriter joxOut = new JOXBeanWriter(sw);
oxOut.writeObject(rootName, object);
joxOut.close();
return sw.toString();
```

The result is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<DOCUMENTO><detalle clase="vo.DetalleVO">
<dateStart>06/03/2017</dateStart>
<localVO>vo.LocaVOB@d5758e</localVO>
</detalle></DOCUMENTO>
```

I have seen that jox invoke toString method, but I'm not able to detect why is converting DetalleVO fine but LocalVO uses Object.toString printing class@hashcode

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

¿How do you implement the Serializable interface in your objects? I’ve been playing with this library and I found that wutka.jox doesn’t parse objects properly when more than one object implement Serializable in the same DTO. Have you tried to make your DTO’s objects to extend from one single parent object that implements Serializable?

Comment: BINGO! That works perfectly for me. I have created a parent bean that implements Serializable and now all my DTOs extend from that bean. The convesion works fine now. Thanks so much!